# Bing API - ready for primetime on a high straffic site?

Tags: search, bing-api

I'm working on an e-commerce site and I need a good search functionality for it. Budget is limited.

I have looked at google site search, and it seems good but I hate being tied to an ongoing cost like that.

Apparently Bing has an API you can query. I wonder, is it ready for use on a highly search-oriented site? Are there any good examples of it being used to good effect that prove it's effectiveness?

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: Facebook uses Bing for everything.

Comment: Love the votes to close without any comments. Awesome. Thanks SO users!

Comment: SO === Wikipedia. Rep whores, spineless bastards, and poseurs round out the bulk of the contributors. Sorry, bro.

Comment: Yeah, it is getting ridiculous here. Thanks for your comment by the way. That answered my question. Make it an answer and I will mark it the answer. Thanks.

Comment: You mean my deslondesoftware.com? Thanks!

Comment: "Love the votes to close without any comments" - You can click on "close" and see the reason for voting to close, which is because this question is considered off-topic on SO.

Comment: Yes, but a useful contributor would make explain why it is off topic and make suggestions to the OP how to make it comply with the SO guidelines. Just voting to close helps no one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook uses Bing for everything, which suggests it's at least propped-up for something like primetime.